# Time and video quality limits on YouTube

Tags: youtube

What is the time limit to a video that I can upload to YouTube? Is there an upper video length that I have to make sure my uploaded videos are under?

Are there other limits or restrictions (quality, resolution, etc) to a YouTube video?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally the limit is **15 minutes**, although [**YouTube has raised this**](http://youtube-global.blogspot.com/2010/12/up-up-and-away-long-videos-for-more.html) for users who have a good history of compliance with their rules.

Answer (score 2):

The current limit is 15 minutes.

if you upload a lot of videos and you get roughly 50-100 views on each video then they will increase your time limit to unlimited allowing you to upload any length video.

Answer (score 2):

Youtube got rid of the 15-minute time limit late last year for "well-behaved" users:

http://gigaom.com/video/youtube-upload-limits/

You can post up to 1080p.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a Youtube uploader, so I don't know under what rules certain user categories fall under, but I've seen videos that break the 15 minute limit by far. So I would guess that 15 minutes is not the upper limit, only that you just gotta figure out the terms of agreement.

Two examples, one lousy called [Longest video on Youtube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p7PqUdTOqSM) (not worth your time, except as an example) and the other - a movie actually - [The man who would be king](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NT1zjOhqwD8) (well worth your time, IMHO).